# JMeter : Use a props.get of String array inside a HTTP request

Tags: jmeter

In my `BeanShell PreProcessor` of my `POST` request, I have the below code:

```
    String[] serversName = new String[]{"FrontEnd", "BackEnd"};
    props.put("serversName",serversName);
```

Now, in the **Body Data** of my **POST** request, I need to call `serverNames` (let's say, I only need the first element). I tried to call it as below:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "name": ${props.get(serversName[${serverIndex}])},
        "ram": 1024,
        "cores": 1,
        "cpuFamily": "AMD_OPTERON",
        "availabilityZone": "AUTO"
    }
```

using `${props.get(serversName[0])` but it complains with **BAD Request 400**!

When I check my request in the listener, it is as below:

```
POST data:
{
    "properties": {
        "name": ${props.get(serversName[0])},
        "ram": 1024,
        "cores": 1,
        "cpuFamily": "AMD_OPTERON",
        "availabilityZone": "AUTO"
    }
```

How to access props variable inside my request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it the *JMeter's way*, by setting Strings ordered with `serversName_[sequence_number]`

```
String[] serversName = new String[]{"FrontEnd", "BackEnd"};
for (int i=0; i < serversName.length; i++) {
    props.put("serversName_" + i, serversName[i]);
}
```

And then just get property `${__P`:

```
${__P(serversName_${serverIndex})}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), the equivalent code would be:

```
String[] serversName = ["FrontEnd", "BackEnd"];
props.put("serversName", serversName);
```

If you want to access property value based on `serverIndex` JMeter Variable value you can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) directly in the HTTP Request sampler body

```
${__groovy(props.get('serversName')[vars.get('serverIndex') as int],)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)